# Symfony : Error when create a Twig Extension function : Call to a member function findAll() on null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, findall, twig-extension

I want to get the list of all the customers to put it in a global variable.

For that, I configure the twig.yaml file:

```
twig:
default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
globals:
    orders: '@App\Twig\OrderExtension'
```

Then, I create a file OrderExtension.php in the folder src>Twig

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use App\Entity\Orders;
use Twig\TwigFunction;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class OrderExtension extends AbstractExtension {
    private $em;

    public function __construt(ManagerRegistry $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('orders', [$this, 'getOrders'])
        ];
    }

    public function getOrders() {
        return $this->em->getRepository(Orders::class)->findAll();

    }

    
}
```

But I have this error : **Call to a member function getRepository() on null**

I tested the global "orders" by changing the getOrders function and asking it to return a simple string.

I called the global in my base.html.twig file and it displayed the desired string.

How do I make sure I get an array of my orders?

Comment: What movitated you to try and register your extension under globals?  The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service) make it clear that you really don't have to do anything by default.  I do find it a bit strange that you are not getting an error with your current setup but comment out the globals section and see what happens.  If you still have trouble then update your question with the twig being used to fire off orders.

Comment: @Cerad I use this way because I want to manipulate the commands in the base.html.twig file. However, no controller renders this view. What do you mean by :. " the twig being used to fire off orders". ?

Comment: Pretty much what the answer below is speculating that you are using.  Like I mentioned, I'm surprised that you are not getting a different sort of error message.  I suspect that your are doing something like `app.orders` but you don't need to.  Twig extensions are already global by default.  You also probably want to typehint against the EntityManagerInterface though I don't think it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all dump $this->em inside your function and make sure that the connection with database exists.

Maybe do not define it as globals, but just call it as a function

```
{{ orders() }}
```

Then you can iterate through this

```
{% for order in orders() %}
{% endfor %}
```